# Proof of $-|z|\le\text{Re}(z)\le |z|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I am looking for the shortest proof of $-|z|\le\text{Re}(z)\le |z|$ for a complex number $z$.

Is there a really nice proof?

Comment: $-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\leq-\sqrt{x^2}= -|x|\leq x \leq |x|=\sqrt{x^2}\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $z = x+yi$, $$x^2 \leq x^2 + y^2 \implies |Re(z)| \leq |z| \implies -|z| \leq Re(z) \leq |z|$$

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Let w be projection of z on real axsis. Then $|z|$ is hypothenus and $|Re(z)|$ is chatetus in right triangle $0zw.$